# Typing "npm" is causing the debugger to attach in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm, terminal, vscode-debugger

When I type `npm` or any other `npm` command, the debugger starts listening and attaches before the command is run. This is occurring in a fresh folder with no files present. Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

Screenshot of issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQuNh.png

Comment: @starball Was going to just add bootstrap to a static website but then saw that the debugger was attaching so I was curious. Turns out I had "debug.javascript.autoAttachFilter": "always" set in my vs code settings. Setting it to "off" fixed it. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

It was found the the issue was due to setting the `debug.javascript.autoAttachFilter` setting to `"always"`, and that setting it to `"disabled"` (the default value) resolved the issue.